# Help with an inequality

Tags: inequality, problem-solving

I ran into this problem a few days ago, and have been trying to prove it, but all my attempts have been unsuccessful.So I am asking for your help. Here's the problem:

If $xy=(x+y)^2-5(x+y)+8$ for some $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ then prove the following inequality holds $x^2+y^2\leq8$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $p=x+y$, $q=x-y$, then
$$\frac{p+q}{2}\frac{p-q}{2}=p^2-5p+8$$
$$3p^2-20p+q^2+32=0$$
$$q^2=-3p^2+20p-32 \ge 0$$
So
$$4\ge p \ge \frac{8}{3}$$
$$p^2+q^2=-2p^2+20p-32=18-2(p-5)^2 \le 18-2(4-5)^2=16$$
$$x^2+y^2=\frac{1}{2}(p^2+q^2)\le 8$$

Comment: Nice answer. I am sure it will get upvoted.

Comment: @DeepSea Thanks! I hope so!

Comment: Much cleaner than what I did.

Comment: Great answer! Quite elegant.

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2 + x(y -5)-5y +y^2+ 8 = 0$$

For this to have a real solution $x$, we have

$$b^2-4ac = (y-5)^2 - 4(y^2-5y+8)\ge 0$$

$$y^2 -10y + 25 -4y^2 +20y -32 \ge 0$$

which reduces to $$(y-1)\left(\frac{7}{3}-y\right)\ge 0 \implies 1 \le y\le 7/3$$

The solution  to the orginal equation is

$$x = \frac{5-y \pm \sqrt{10y - 3y^2-7}}{2}$$

and so $$x^2 = \frac{(5-y)^2 + (10y - 3y^2-7) + 2(5-y)\sqrt{10y - 3y^2-7}}{4}$$

$$x^2 +y^2 =  \frac{4y^2+(5-y)^2 + (10y - 3y^2-7) + 2(5-y)\sqrt{10y - 3y^2-7}}{4}$$

where $1\le y\le7/3$

some brute force differentiation shows that the function on the right achieves its maxima 8 at $y=2$

Comment: There is probably a more elegant way of solving this.

Comment: Thank you. This seems correct. Turns out I messed up some calculations and mistakenly got that there are no real solutions :)

Answer (score 1):

*A simple solution with Vieta's relations*:

Set $s=x+y,\;p=xy$. The relation between $x$ and $y$ rewrites as $p=s^2-5s+8$, so 
$$x^2+y^2=s^2-2p=-s^2+10s-16.$$
This is a quadratic polynomial in $s$. Its maximum is obtained for $s=5$, and it is equal to $9$.

Furthermore, the equation $\;t^2-st+p=0$ must have real roots, which means its discriminant $$\Delta(s)=s^2-4p=-3s^2+20s-32=(s-4)(8-3s)$$ is positive.

So the maximum of $f(s)=-s^2+10s-16$ on the domain for which $x$ and $y$ exist, is equal to
$$\max(f(4),f(8/3))=f(4)=8.$$

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: Use Lagrange Multiplier !. I think LM does a very good job with this particular problem. It bypasses the cumbersome part of the work.

Comment: I got the same thing and that's why i posted it here, was wondering if there was another approach to this. Maybe there is a mistake in the problem. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Let $x+y=2u$ and $xy=v^2$, where $v^2$ can be negative.

Hence, $v^2=4u^2-10u+8$.

But $4u^2-10u+8=v^2\leq u^2$, which gives $\frac{4}{3}\leq u\leq2$, and we need to prove that
$$4u^2-2v^2\leq8$$ or
$$2u^2-(4u^2-10u+8)\leq4$$ or
$$u^2-5u+6\geq0$$ or
$$(u-2)(u-3)\geq0,$$
which is true for $\frac{4}{3}\leq u\leq2$.

Done!

Comment: Um, $(u-2)(u-3)\ge0$ is true for $u\le2$ or $u\ge3$ not what you wrote. And I don't understand how you know that $u$ will satisfy those bounds.

Comment: @Guy Because $4u^2-10u+8\leq u^2$ it's $3u^2-10u+8\leq0$ or $(3u-4)(u-2)\leq0$ or $\frac{4}{3}\leq u\leq2$, which gives $u\leq2$ and $(u-2)(u-3)\geq0$.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. I missed the upper part of your answer, don't know how. Thanks. But how do you know that $u=x+y$ will stay less than 2, which is what we have to prove, given the original relation between $x$ and $y$

Comment: @Guy I wrote $2u=x+y$. From here $v^2\leq u^2$ it's $xy\leq\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)^2$ or $(x-y)^2\geq0$.